# Android webview loads content sometimes

Tags: android, webview, loading

I have a problem with the webview, as it sometimes loads the content and sometimes not.
I have noticed that there is no problem with the 2.2 and 2.3.3 Android versions, only with the 4.0.4 Android versions.

My code is:

```
public class MywebviewActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.mywebview);
    final Activity MywebviewActivity = this;        
      // Makes Progress bar Visible
      getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
      android.webkit.WebView wv = 
      (android.webkit.WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView); 
      wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {     
      public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
      {
       //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
          MywebviewActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
          MywebviewActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

      // Return the app name after finish loading
      if(progress == 100)
          MywebviewActivity.setTitle(R.string.web_app_name);
        }
  });

      wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
      wv.loadUrl("http://mypagename.com/android/server/app/ver10/page1.html");

    }

public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware acceleration carries out all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas using the GPU .
Check whether the application is hardware accelerated:

> View.isHardwareAccelerated()

returns true if the View is attached to a hardware accelerated window. If it returns false
 , add

> android:hardwareAccelerated ="true"

for the `<activity`

element in Manifest file .